# scala for mapbox vector tiles - getting an 'id' field into the Features written to vector tiles

Tags: scala, vector-tiles, geotrellis

I'm writing MapBox vector tiles using geotrellis vectorpipe.

see here for the basic flow: https://geotrellis.github.io/vectorpipe/usage.html

Typically GeoJson Features can have an `id` field, so that Features can be rolled up into FeatureCollections.  I need to make use of this field, but vectorpipe doesn't (natively) have this capability.

This is the `Feature` type used, and you can see it only has space for 1) a `Geometry` and 2) a data object `D` (which ends up populating `properties` in the output).  There is no spot for an `id`.

https://geotrellis.github.io/scaladocs/latest/index.html#geotrellis.vector.Feature

Upstream there's a method called `writeFeatureJsonWithID()` that does let you inject an `id` field into a `Feature` when writing GeoJson.

https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/blob/master/vector/src/main/scala/geotrellis/vector/io/json/FeatureFormats.scala#L41-L49

**My question is this:**

I have worked through the vectorpipe code (https://github.com/geotrellis/vectorpipe), and I can't figure out if/where the data ever exists as GeoJson in a way where I can override and inject the `id`, maybe using the `writeFeatureJsonWithID()` or something I write explicitly.  A lot of conversions are implicit, but it also may never explicitly sit as json.

Any ideas for how to get an `id` field in the final GeoJson written to vector tiles?

**EDIT**

Right now I think the trick is going to be finding a way to override `.unfeature()` method here:

https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/blob/master/vectortile/src/main/scala/geotrellis/vectortile/Layer.scala

The problem is that the `internal.vector_tile.Tile` is private, so I can construct it without forking the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to fork geotrellis, hard-code a `metadata => id` function in `Layer.unfeature()` and compile locally to include in my project.  Not ideal, but it works fine.

Also opened an issue here: https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/issues/2884